# Way of knowing DLL's visual studio compiler version at run-time

Tags: visual-studio, dll

I have looked and didn't find similar question.

I have an application (exe or dll) which loads another dll via Loadlibrary.

Is there any way which I can know in run time (i.e., **after** Loadlibrary)
which version of visual studio compiled this dll?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Hans Passant I have 2 black box DLLS: one was compiled in VS2008 and the other in VS2013. I need to call some functions on these DLLs (not together) from another DLL (the caller DLL). The problem is some of these functions accept std::string which has different implementation in each version so the caller DLLs have to be compiled in the correct versions (i.e., I have to compile 2 callers). So, this is the reason I want to know on run time which caller I should use. Appreciate any **practical** help.